# java coding assignment explanation in private void

Tags: java, private, void

can someone explain me how this is working ? i'm getting c as my output, it's my 3rd day on java . Thanx in advance

```
class adarsh
{
  private void print( ){
    System.out.println("a");
  }
  private void print(String str){
    System.out.println("b");
  }
  private void print(int x){
    System.out.println("c");
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    adarsh object = new adarsh();
    object.print(12);
  }
}
```

Comment: Learn to use a debugger; you'll benefit much more from learning yourself than from us telling you the answer.

Comment: You get `c` because you call the method which took an int `print(12)`, another thing please start with reading [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: It is called "method overloading" in java

Comment: check this out https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/

Answer (score 2):

Then a class has multiple methods with the same name and different parameter lists, it's called *method overloading*. `print` is an overloaded method in your class. When you use it, the method that gets used depends on the number and type of the arguments you use in the call: The best matching method is used. Because you used `12`, which is an integer literal, it has the type `int`, so `print(int)` was called. If you'd used no argument, `print()` would have been called. If you'd used `print("foo")`, `print(String)` would have been called.

---

Side note: Please use the [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), at least when asking for help (but it's best when not asking for help, too). Your class should be called `Adarsh`, not `adarsh`.

Comment: What input should I give in object.print(); to print 'a'

Comment: @ghost_83 - As I said above, *"If you'd used no argument, `print()` would have been called."*

Comment: There in my code i did a small change by adding
                                           private void print(float f){
     System.out.println("x");                     
}
             And adding this at the bottom
object.print(15.22);
                                  it didn't compile...  What am i doing wrong out here

Comment: @ghost_83 - The error message tells you why: There's no `print(double)`. `15.22` is a `double`, not a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

See [Method overloading in Java](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/). The method having the signature `private void print(int x)` was picked by the compiler, since you passed print an int.

Answer (score 1):

What you have tried is an example of **Method Overloading** which allows different methods to have the **same name**, but different signatures where the signature can differ by the number of input parameters or type of input parameters or both.

In your code, object.print(12) matches the method based on type of argument. 
You call the method by passing an **int** 12 so the method with **int as an argument** is invoked and it prints **c**

**Use of Overloading**

We don’t have to create and remember different names for functions doing the same thing. For example, in your code, if overloading was not supported by Java, you would have to create method names like print1, print2, print3 … etc..  though all methods do the same printing work. Thus improves readability of code.

And one more thing, Please use the Java Naming Conventions

- Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalised.
- Use whole words and must avoid acronyms and abbreviations.